# Getting CPU Temperature, storing it in VAR and sending it to a server

Tags: bash, shell, curl

Wenn I use `sensors` I get this output

```
cpu_thermal-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +55.0 C  (crit = +120.0 C)
```

I just need the **+55.0 C** to be stored in a variable **temp** and send it to a server:

```
curl -i -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{ "id":"2","timestamp":"100","data":"temp"}' https://dv7knsjzph.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/boxtronic-devices/2/data/
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: Like written I just need the 55.0 to be stored in a variable temp. So how do I get it  and in which form should I replace the second  "data"  in curl so that it contains the 55
I am using a for loop that gives temperature every 1 second

Comment: @Spearitch502 the format will depend on what the server is expecting. We have no clue what that is, so we can't help you. If this is your server, using an API you developed, then  you should know. If this is not yours, you need to look at the documentation of whatever it is you are using and figure out what format it expects. So all we can answer here is how to get the `+55.0 C` into a variable.

Comment: Is that the full output of your `sensors` command? You only get three lines?

Comment: @terdon yes why ? I am using an STM32MP157C-DK2 with buildroot as main distro. I activated all the sensors in the menuconfig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bsh
TEMP=$(sensors -j | jq '."cpu_thermal-virtual-0"."temp1"."temp1_input"')
curl -i -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{ "id":"2","timestamp":"100","data":"'${TEMP}'"}' https://dv7knsjzph.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/boxtronic-devices/2/data/
```

`$()` is to receive the output and save it to the variable `TEMP` (like backticks `` ` `` but can be encapsulated)

`-j` for the `sensors`-command outputs the data json-formatted

`jq` is a tool to operate on json. The usage of the quotes is important because `-` has a special meaning for `jq`. The output of the part inside of `$()` should be the raw temperature.

On the `curl`-line the temperature gets injected from the `TEMP`-variable. Note that this must be outside of any single-quotation because otherwise it will stay as `${TEMP}` instead of replaced by the variables content. The curly braces are optional but recommended.

Comment: Thank you that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
temp=`sensors | awk '/temp1/{print $2}'`

curl -i -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{ \"id\":\"2\",\"timestamp\":\"100\",\"data\":\"$temp\"}" $URL
```